# how to change 2 elements at once with addEventListener javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

So i have a classList.toggle which simply open and close a dropdown menu, with a second toggle changing the class for an arrow (up and down).

I want to be able to close the dropdown menu by clicking outside it.

I have managed to achieve this for either the dropdown, or the arrow. not both at once.

How can i click outside the dropdown menu while having both events happening simultanously?

I should say that this is W3s method of doing it.

Still new to javascript, any help would appreciated!

Thanks,

Here is what i have:

```
function dropdownsortby() {
   document.getElementById("arrow").classList.toggle("down");
   document.getElementById("hidedefault").classList.toggle("show");
}

    window.onclick = function(event) { 
  if (!event.target.matches('.Sortby')) { 

    var arrow = document.getElementsByClassName("up"); 
    var i; 
    for (i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) { 
      var changearrow = arrow[i]; 
      if (changearrow.classList.contains('down')) { 
        changearrow.classList.remove('down'); 
      }
    }
  }
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.Sortby')) { 


    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("sortbybuttons");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After glancing at the code you have, I'm thinking that your issue comes with assigning an `onclick` event to the `window` object twice, which by my understanding would overwrite whatever first `onclick` function was assigned first. My recommended approach would be to combine both functions into one `onclick` event since they both seemed to be wrapped by the same `if` statement, and the functionality of each one doesn't seem to conflict with the other. The following snippet demonstrates how this would look.

```
window.onclick = function(event) { 
  if (!event.target.matches('.Sortby')) { 

    let arrow = document.getElementsByClassName("up"); 
    for (let i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) { 
      var changearrow = arrow[i]; 
      if (changearrow.classList.contains('down')) { 
        changearrow.classList.remove('down'); 
      }
    }

   var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("sortbybuttons");
   for (let j = 0; j < dropdowns.length; j++) {
     var openDropdown = dropdowns[j];
     if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
       openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, this solved my problem. The only having one window.onclick makes sense. So 'j' is used if 'i' has already had something assigned to it?

Comment: Not entirely, I just used `j` instead of `i` to demonstrate that they are two different iterator variables. If you wanted to use `i` for both `for` loops you could do it like this

`var i;`
`for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { ... }`
`for (i = 0; i < m; i++) { ... }`

This method - which has many variations - would allow you to use the same variable multiple times. Sorry for weird formatting, comments aren't the best for positing code.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just combine both sets of logic into the same handler?

```
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.Sortby')) {
        var arrow = document.getElementsByClassName("up");
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("sortbybuttons");
        var i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
            var changearrow = arrow[i];
            if (changearrow.classList.contains('down')) {
                changearrow.classList.remove('down');
            }
        }

        for (j = 0; j < dropdowns.length; j++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[j];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```